# Meaning of L near text in define

Tags: c++

I came across something I can't search for what it means.

```
#define DEFAULT_KEY L"text"
```

What does 'L' mean or do?

Other example that I found

```
wcscat(xpath, L"\\");
```

Comment: specifies that the string is wide characters. Also, try searching.

Comment: My english is not that good, so I couldn't find in my searches.

Comment: Search [L string c++](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=L+string+%5Bc%2B%2B%5D)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means the string literal has type `const wchar_t*`, which is a type different that `const char*`. It is usually used to store Unicode strings.

Some APIs (particularly the Windows API) use this type all over the place.

Answer (score 0):

The L prefix denotes a wide character/string literal; i.e., it is of type wchar_t instead of char. Unicode based programs typically use wide strings, while ANSI/ASCII based programs typically do not.